# Plotting variable number of series in ggplot for use in Shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I need to make a graph with ggplot where the number of series included in the plot is variable.  The dataframe has dates (x variable) in the first column, and then anywhere from 1 to 15 additional columns containing variables to be plotted.  I saw a previous post suggesting melt from the reshape package; however, I could not get that to work.  I would like this to work regardless of the ncol= specification while dimming the test matrix.  Really appreciate any help on this!

Simulated data:

```
#rm(list = ls())

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

test <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 5)

test[,1] <- seq(from = 2000, by = 1, length = 10)

for(i in 2:5){

  test[1, i] <-  100

  for(j in 2:10){

    test[j, i] <- test[j-1, i] + rnorm(1, 25, 5)

  }
}

colnames(test)[1] <- "date"

melt_test <- melt(test, id = "date")

ggplot(melt_test, aes(x=date, y=value, colour = variable, group = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Avoid adding `rm(list=ls())` in public code.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work? It helps to see an error/warning message, or to see the output and you explain what is not right about it. (You might alternately use `tidyr::gather` or `data.table::melt`, not sure if there are significant feature or performance differences, but both work well for my needs.)

Comment: @r2evans I need to create a plot with a variable number of series.  I would like to pass a "group" of data series to the y= input in ggplot(aes()).  Currently, the above code creates a long data format while adding 2 columns, Var1 and Var2.  I would like Var1 to be the dates, and Var2 a grouping variable by column.  Here is my error message: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'variable' not found

Comment: the values you pass in `aes(...)` are supposed to be names of columns in `melt_test` so since there is no column named "variable" you are getting that error. If you adjust to use "Var1" and "Var2" instead you should get a plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixing the data:**

Your code produces an error

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

so I'll regenerate the data more directly into a `data.frame` vice a `matrix`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
test <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 4)
set.seed(2) # for reproducibility, always include this in SO questions when using random funcs
for(i in 1:4){
  test[1,i] <- 100
  for(j in 2:10){
    test[j, i] <- test[j-1, i] + rnorm(1, 25, 5)
  }
}
test[1:3,]
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
# [1,] 100.0000 100.0000 100.0000 100.0000
# [2,] 120.5154 124.3061 130.0641 122.0172
# [3,] 146.4397 151.3943 157.2255 150.9782
dat <- cbind.data.frame(date = seq(2000, by=1, length=nrow(test)), test)
dat[1:3,]
#   date        1        2        3        4
# 1 2000 100.0000 100.0000 100.0000 100.0000
# 2 2001 120.5154 124.3061 130.0641 122.0172
# 3 2002 146.4397 151.3943 157.2255 150.9782
```

Now, when we reshape, we can see something better:

```
melt_dat <- reshape2::melt(dat, id="date")
melt_dat[1:3,]
#   date variable    value
# 1 2000        1 100.0000
# 2 2001        1 120.5154
# 3 2002        1 146.4397
```

Now things work:

```
ggplot(melt_dat, aes(x=date, y=value, colour = variable, group = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image: sample ggplot image]

Comment: Ah ok, so the error was caused by the test data being in a matrix rather than the dataframe.  Thanks so much for you help @r2evans !